# URL rewrites issues

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are having a problem with URL rewrites on an apache server using .htaccess.

Goal: to have the following URL stripped of its category & subcategory while leaving the generic redirect in place.

Test 1:

`Redirect   301 /category/subcategory/product http://www.site.com/product`

Redirect works perfectly. A single redirect to the desired page.

Test 2:

`RedirectMatch  301 ^/category/subcategory/.*$  http://www.site.com/category/subcategory`

Redirect on its own works perfectly for all URLs desired.

The problem is when we have both URLs in a clean .htaccess file, and the redirects are in the proper order (specific first, then general), the general redirect is being used.

Test 3:

`Redirect   301 /category/subcategory/product http://www.site.com/product`

`RedirectMatch  301 ^/category/subcategory/.*$  http://www.site.com/category/subcategory`

When we visit www.site.com/category/subcategory/product, the result is www.site.com/category/subcategory/product, That is not the desired result. Instead, we want the URL to be www.site.com/category/subcategory/product,

We have even tried modified the Redirect to: 
`Redirect   301 /category/subcategory/product http://www.site.com/product [L]`
It made no difference.

Please help!

**EDIT: Added 3/25/2014**

What we are trying to do is provide specific redirects for a group of known products from their old product page to the new product page. We are also trying to add a "catch all" redirect for the remaining unknown products to the category page.

Here is an actual example redirect which works:

`Redirect   301 /womens/western-dresses/stetson-cream-empire-waist-ls-western-dress http://www.site.com/stetson-cream-empire-waist-ls-western-dress`

If the above redirect is added to the .htaccess file, it works perfectly on its own.

Here is a second example redirect which works:

`RedirectMatch  301 ^/womens/western-dresses/.*$    http://www.site.com/womens/western-dresses`

The problem is if we have both of the rules together in .htaccess, in the same order as above, the second rule is always triggered. We try to access www.site.com/womens/western-dresses/stetson-cream-empire-waist-ls-western-dress and the result is www.site.com/womens/western-dresses instead of the desired result of www.site.com/stetson-cream-empire-waist-ls-western-dress

For clarity:

- if we remove the .htaccess file, the URL 404s
- if only the first rule is listed, it triggers perfectly
- if only the second rule is listed, the second rule triggers perfectly
- if both rules are listed, the second rule triggers.
- We have deleted all redirects from the .htaccess file. The only redirects are the below two lines. The issue remains where the first redirect is ignored. We have tried changing the start of the first redirect to ^/womens and ^womens but that change had no effect.

`Redirect   301 /womens/western-dresses/stetson-cream-empire-waist-ls-western-dress http://www.site.com/stetson-cream-empire-waist-ls-western-dress`

`RedirectMatch  301 ^/womens/western-dresses/.*$    http://www.site.com/womens/western-dresses`

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little confusing, so I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

If memory serves, you should not include a leading slash in your pattern when using these directives in a `.htaccess` file. That usage is reserved for httpd.conf. When these directives are used in a `.htaccess` file, the leading path components have already been stripped by mod_access. I am guessing this is the cause of your troubles.

For example, this should work (not tested):

```
Redirect      301 ^category/subcategory/product http://www.site.com/product
RedirectMatch 301 ^category/subcategory/.*      http://www.site.com/category/subcategory
```

As an aside, `[L]` is mod_rewrite lingo. "Redirect" and "RedirectMatch" are part of mod_access.

**EDIT 3/25:**

Redirect and RedirectMatch can be fussy when used in .htaccess files, particularly when dealing with non-existent folders and mixed directives. Can I suggest you move directly to mod_rewrite? While it has a steep learning curve, you will never go back once you get the hang of it.

```
# Assuming you are in a .htaccess under DocumentRoot:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/subcategory/product1\.html$ /product1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/subcategory/product2\.html$ /product2.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/subcategory/.*              /category/subcategory [R=301,L]
```

As an aside, this looks like a good candidate for [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html), although you will need to declare the map in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Hi codnodder - thank you for your response! I received more clarification to add above.

Comment: Updated answer using mod_rewrite. If your paths are different, we made need to do some adjustments with RewriteBase and the like.